# Delete without ClientID - User Deletion API Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, userid, clientid

I have a question regarding `User Deletion API` for Google Analytics. We have a Property and View that does not collect `UserID` or `ClientID` as `Custom Dimension`, but we have a lot of `PII` data in our Events report *(emails and phone numbers).*

When i go to `User Explorer` i can get the `ClientID`, but unfortunately as far as i know this report is not available in any API versions of Google Analytics.

My question is **HOW** can i then delete all these `PII` without knowing the `ClientID`? I do not have a 360 account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Unfortunately I think you've done your research correctly and I'm afraid there aren't more options available than what you already listed:*

**You have 2 ways of deleting data:**

1. User Deletion API
2. Deleting views (I know it's too radical, but that's the only other option)

As for option 1, **indeed, none of the reporting APIs expose the `Client ID` or the `User ID`**, so you have 2 options:

- **Export the Client ID manually**  from the User Explorer report, but you won't be able tell which `PII` is associated with which `Client ID`
- **Implement a custom dimension** to store the Client ID so you can then identify the corresponding `PII`, and automate that process if you want to

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Max. Ill give the User Deletion API with the options you listed a try. Ill also just create a new view right away just in case so i wont miss data while i work on your solution.

Comment: You're welcome. If you learn some things in the process feel free to post those as comment here to help those trying after you